# gawk: presenting two operations outcome in two rows

Tags: printing, awk, gawk

I have a program which output is summary file with header and few columns of results.
I want to show only two data: file name and best period prediction and I use this command:

```
program input_file | gawk 'NR==2 {print $3}; NR==4 {print $2}'
```

as the result I obtain result in one column, two lines. What I have to do to have this result in one line, two columns?

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
program input_file | gawk 'NR==2 {heading = $3}; NR==4 {print heading " = " $2}'
```

This saves the value in `$3` on line 2 in variable `heading` and prints the heading and the value from column 2 when it reads line 4.